# Add UTM?Xy /Lat long to attribute table for point data in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am running V QGIS 3.2.3.  I have found some answers on here how to do this but in previous versions. Is there a simple way to calculate/Add Xy or utm coordinates to the attribute table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is the "Add geometry attributes" tool from the Processing Toolbox.

Processing> Toolbox> Search for Add geometry attributes.

It will create new columns. For polygons and lines you will have to decide what X and Y you want to add, for example centroids.

Comment: that worked. thank you !